# "Eu tinha um amigo que é/era judeu"

Tags: tempo-verbal

Se estou contando uma história a respeito de um antigo amigo com uma condição que permanece até os dias de hoje (ex: ser judeu), devo conjugar o verbo "ser" no passado também ou no presente? Ou tanto faz?

Comment: Em minha humilde opnião você deve ver a resposta do @Centaurus. Conjugar o verbo ter no passado dá a entender que ele já faleceu ou deixou de ser seu amigo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se usas **é**, estás a afirmar a condição de ele ser judeu é verdadeira no momento em que afirmação é feita. Podia ser judeu na altura da história ou não.

Se usas **era** estás a dizer que a condição de ele ser judeu é verdadeira no teu ponto de referência no passado, mas podia ser verdadeira antes desse ponto e pode ter continuado a ser verdade até ao presente (contrariamente a "ele foi judeu").

Portanto, ambas são ambíguas. A primeira deixa em aberto a condição no passado, a segunda deixa em aberto a condição no presente. O melhor é dizer **amigo judeu**, sem verbo.

Agora, tudo dependerá do contexto, mas sem mais a leitura mais provável com **é** é de que a condição era também verdadeira no passado (porque havias tu de mencionar um facto não aplicável ao momento da tua história?). Com **era**, a leitura mais fácil depende. Se o interlocutor sabe que já não o vês há muitos anos, não assumirá que a afirmação fornece informação sobre o presente e sem prova em contrário uma pessoa não terá mudado de religião. Caso contrário, pensará que escolheste explicitamente **era** em vez do simples **amigo judeu** para indicar que já não é verdade no presente.

Portanto, se quiseres mesmo usar o verbo, a melhor forma depende do contexto. Dizes "antigo amigo", mas essa expressão é ela mesma ambígua. Pode significar "amigo atual de longa data", ou "amigo na altura, mas não no presente". Ora, se ele ainda é teu amigo, presumivelmente sabes que ele é ainda judeu e a melhor forma é **é**. Se já não é teu amigo e não sabes a sua condição no presente, a melhor forma é **era**. Podes também dizer *amigo que era e é judeu*, se não quiseres deixar dúvidas.

Answer (score 7):

As duas alternativas são possíveis. Mas se começamos com **tinha**, tipicamente vamos contar alguma coisa que se passou nesse tempo. Então dizer **que é** vai causar uma certa dissonância. Comparemos:

> (a) *Tinha um amigo que é judeu. Um dia convidámo-lo para jantar e*...
>   (b) *Tinha um amigo que era judeu. Um dia convidámo-lo para jantar e*...
>   (c) *Tinha um amigo que é vegetariano. Um dia convidámo-lo para jantar e*...

Para mim (b) soa melhor, apesar de (a) também estar correto. A frase (c) tem um problema adicional: não sabemos se antes o amigo já era vegetariano; no caso de *ser judeu*, presumimos que se agora é, dantes também era.

Mesmo quando queremos enfatizar a condição presente, é comum usar um advérbio para ajudar a transição do referencial temporal:

> (d) *Tinha um amigo que agora é vegetariano.* (Dá ideia que antes não era.)
>   (e) *Tinha um amigo que ainda hoje é vegetariano.* (Sugere que há razão para um dia não ser.)

Os dois exemplos anteriores mostram que *tinha um amigo que é* está correto: não é por tirarmos o *agora* ou *ainda hoje* que as frases deixariam de estar corretas.  Mas (d) e (e) não são apropriados para *ser judeu* (pelas razões entre parênteses). E se dissermos *tinha um amigo que era* deixamos em dúvida se ele ainda é. Se quiséssemos eliminar essa dúvida, eu optaria por:

> (f) Tinha um amigo judeu. Um dia convidámo-lo para jantar e...
>   (g) Tinha um amigo que era judeu. (Era e é.) Um dia convidámo-lo para jantar e...

Answer (score 3):

De uma forma **resumida e didática:**

(A palavra "judeu" nos exemplos **refere-se tão somente à religião, e não à etnia.**)

- "Eu tenho um amigo que é judeu." - **Ele é meu amigo, é judeu, e está vivo.**
- "Eu tenho um amigo que era judeu." - **Ele continua sendo meu amigo mas não é mais judeu.** (ou mudou de religião, ou virou ateu)
- "Eu tinha um amigo que é judeu." - **Ele era meu amigo e já não é mais, mas continua sendo judeu e ainda está vivo.**
- "Eu tinha um amigo que era judeu." - **Ele era meu amigo, já não é mais, e provavelmente já faleceu ou mudou de religião.**